# How can I find games similar to a certain type?

Tags: patchwork

I have recently been playing a lot of the game "Patchwork" (https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/163412/patchwork) and really am enjoying it, but it becomes redundant quickly as it is a two player game. I'm looking to find more games of this type so that I can have a game rotation. I'm just not sure on how I can find games that are similar in quality, fun, game time, complexity, etc.

So what would be a good way other than reading all the reviews on websites or forums to find same style games?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is ambiguous as to what the "certain type" really is. If you look on the ["full credits"](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/163412/patchwork/credits) notebook page for that game you'll find the "Categories", "Mechanisms" and "Families" which have been listed for that game.

You can search for various combinations of "Categories" and "Mechanisms" using the [advanced search](https://boardgamegeek.com/advsearch/boardgame) option. For instance [this BGG search](https://boardgamegeek.com/geeksearch.php?action=search&advsearch=1&objecttype=boardgame&q=&include%5Bdesignerid%5D=&geekitemname=&include%5Bpublisherid%5D=&geekitemname=&range%5Byearpublished%5D%5Bmin%5D=&range%5Byearpublished%5D%5Bmax%5D=&range%5Bminage%5D%5Bmax%5D=&floatrange%5Bavgrating%5D%5Bmin%5D=&floatrange%5Bavgrating%5D%5Bmax%5D=&range%5Bnumvoters%5D%5Bmin%5D=&floatrange%5Bavgweight%5D%5Bmin%5D=&floatrange%5Bavgweight%5D%5Bmax%5D=&range%5Bnumweights%5D%5Bmin%5D=&colfiltertype=&searchuser=herace&range%5Bminplayers%5D%5Bmax%5D=&range%5Bmaxplayers%5D%5Bmin%5D=&playerrangetype=normal&range%5Bleastplaytime%5D%5Bmin%5D=&range%5Bplaytime%5D%5Bmax%5D=&propertyids%5B%5D=1009&propertyids%5B%5D=2002&B1=Submit) yields the games which are in the "abstract strategy" Category and use the "tile placement" mechanism.

There isn't any way to restrict a search to/through a "Family". You'll just have to spin through the whole list for each family. There are a lot of games in the Combinatorial family (and the BGG family misses many since this is a "new" family). There are also a lot of games in the Polyominoes family.

Answer (score 4):

If you look under the "Classification" section on the game's BGG page, you can click one of those tags to see other games with similar features. E.g.: https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgamemechanic/2041/card-drafting

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The problem with this is that there are many classifications per game and so it will get me a wide variety of games. Your example is a good one as it has  "card drafting" as a mechanism, but there aren't even any cards in the game. So I guess I'm looking for a sort of "if you liked this, you may also like..."

Comment: BGG also has an Advanced Search page where you can search by multiple tags. My suggestion would be to look through the top-scoring (Geek Rating or Avg Rating) games in each category, and see if any look appealing to you. It's just that you're getting into very subjective territory, where you and I might even disagree about what games are similar to another. The search tools on BGG can narrow your consideration from "All board games ever" (which is mostly what an Amazon recommendation would give you) to 15 or 20 good games that have at least something in common with the one you like.

Comment: Of course, Amazon recommendations aren't horrible.

Comment: Good idea, I'll look at the ratings for each category and try an do a correlation. Tahnks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

If the (advanced) search results of BGG do not satisfy you you should try to find additional keywords. One solution is to click on the Designer of the game you are looking for. In the case of Patchwork this is Uwe Rosenberg. There you get a list of all games he designed. If you look at the games you will find that ["A Feast for Odin"](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/177736/feast-odin) (a more complex game) and ["Cottage Garden"](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/204027/cottage-garden) (more or less the same complexity as patchwork) use the same puzzling mechanism. If you check these BGG pages you can find additional Categories and Mechanisms for such games and use them in the advanced search.

Comment: Awesome, just looked at Cottage Garden and am definitely buying it. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I just played **Cottage Garden** at BGG.con and it should be a fresh, 2-4player experience for fans of **Patchwork**